# Copy data from csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to follow one copy_from example describe in stackoverflow but i modify little as i need to read data from csv file. Following this example i wrote a small program where the file is to be readed from file stored in disk and then copy data from that file to created table, My code is :

```
def importFile():
    path = "C:\myfile.csv"
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("Drop table if exists test_copy; ")
    data = StringIO.StringIO()
    data.write(path)
    data.seek(0)
    curs.copy_from(data, 'MyTable')
    print("Data copied")
```

But i get error,

psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer:

Does this mean there is mismatch between csv file and my table? OR is this syntax enough in order to copy csv file? or I need some more code ?? I am new to python, so any help will be appreciated..

Comment: It looks like your data is in different format than expected by PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your .csv file with a text editor. You want to be sure that

- the field-separator is a tab character
- there are no quote-chars
- there is no header row

If this is true, the following should work:

```
import psycopg2

def importFromCsv(conn, fname, table):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        conn.cursor().copy_from(inf, table)

def main():
    conn = ??  # set up database connection
    importFromCsv(conn, "c:/myfile.csv", "MyTable")
    print("Data copied")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am looking forward to copy csv file where the field are seperated by ; and each field are enclosed in double quote. But I don't have header...

Comment: what if all fields in CSV are in quotes?